# SignalR issue with invoking server method from onreceived method

Tags: c#, signalr.client

I have following SignalR code for desktop client:

> ```
>     _hub.On<String>("Ping",(string s) =>
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine(s + " from MainHub "); 
>                 _hub.Invoke("Acknowledge","Say Hello to MainHub"); 
>             });
> ```
>
> I have Ping and Acknowledge method on Hub.
>   But
>
> ```
> _hub.Invoke("Acknowledge","Say Hello to MainHub");
> ```

is not firing properly from desktop client.
How to write this code properly?

Comment: Have you tried awaiting the _hub.Invoke call?

Comment: @Pawel when i use await _hub.Invoke call, it gives me "Possible deadlock detected. A callback registered with "HubProxy.On" or "Connect ion.Received" has been executing for at least 10 seconds." error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [Link](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3167)

**Currently in the .NET client we serialize invoking user callbacks upon receiving messages from the server using a TaskQueue. This includes callbacks registered using HubProxy.On or continuations after HubProxy.Invoke.
If these callbacks block, especially blocking waiting on result from another callback, the receive dispatch queue will simply stop (deadlock).
We should detect this condition and trace an error when it occurs (Connection.OnError).
We could do this in the TaskQueue itself (with an optional flag that enables it of course) that makes it essentially monitor itself, using an async loop started on the first enqueue that checks if the task currently running is the same as what was running on the last interval. If so, log the error.**

Now I have managed to fix this issue by a quick but dirty solution. I know this is not the way to fix this issue, but I dont have any choices other than this. Other solution better than this is higly appreciated.

```
 Threading.Timer tmr= new Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Acknowledge),null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);

 private void Acknowldege(object state)
  {
   if(SignalRIsReady)//check if signalr is ready
     {
       _hub.Invoke("Acknowledge","Say Hello to MainHub"); 
       tmr.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);//wait until next event occurs
     }
  }

 _hub.On<String>("Ping",(string s) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s + " from MainHub "); 
            tmr.Change(50, Timeout.Infinite);// call callback after 50ms

        });
```

Another Solution I have managed is using configureawait. Following is the solution:

```
   _hub.On<String>("Ping",async(string s) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s + " from MainHub "); 
          await Task.Run(async()=>{
              _hub.Invoke("Acknowledge","Say Hello to MainHub"); 
          }).ConfigureAwait(false);//this will run the task to seperate thread, unblocking the parent thread

        });
```